# How do I bind specific columns to a DataGrid using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, datagrid

I have a SQL table with ~20 columns. I want to pull 3 columns from it and populate a datagrid in my front end WPF application. Here's my code so far.

```
 Private Sub AccountSelectorDialogue_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e 
 As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

    Try
        Dim context As MyDatabase = New MyDatabase

        Dim qry_Accounts = From accounts In context.tbl_Accounts
                           Order By accounts.AccName
                           Select {accounts.AccName, accounts.AccPhone, accounts.ParentAcc}
        Dim results = qry_Accounts.ToList()

        AccountDataGrid.DataContext = results

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while selecting record from table..." & ex.Message, "Select Records")
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

When I load the datagrid, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV9En.png) exception and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTv8f.png) inner exception. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental but I don't see it.

Edit: The exceptions disappear when I write the `Select` line like this and delete the `results` variable.

```
 Select {accounts.AccName, accounts.AccPhone,      accounts.ParentAcc}.ToList()
 AccountDataGrid.DataContext = qry_Accounts
```

However, the datagrid still doesn't show anything.

Edit 2: Using `ItemsSource` instead of `DataContext`. Now the datagrid shows the right number of rows - but they're empty...

Edit 3: After staring at my screen for a few hours, I think it may be my xaml. Originally I didn't think I had to bind my columns. If I do need to, I don't know how to in this context.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AccountDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"      
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="480" 
MinHeight="200"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Background="Transparent" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AccountName" Binding="
{Binding AccName}" Header="Account Name" Width="Auto" MinWidth="180"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PhoneNumber" Binding="
{Binding AccPhone}" Header="Phone" Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AccountOwnerAlias" 
 Binding="{Binding ParentAcc}" Header="Account Owner Alias" Width="Auto" 
 MinWidth="150"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What are they types of {accounts.AccName, accounts.AccPhone, accounts.ParentAcc}.  I'm guessing that ParentAcc is a Navigation Property, not a scalar value.

Comment: They're all strings (nchar in database)

Comment: this line looks odd to me 
  ~Dim context As MyDatabase = New MyDatabase~
Can we see the code for your DBContext ? 
How are you sending the connection string ?

Comment: MyDatabase is the name of the data access class that I created automatically using entity framework. I doubt there's an issue there - I have many other queries working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only bind to public *properties*, you need to define the properties of your anonymous type:

```
Select New With { .AccName = accounts.AccName, .AccPhone = accounts.AccPhone, .ParentAcc = accounts.ParentAcc }.ToList()
AccountDataGrid.DataContext = qry_Accounts
```

If you want to be able to edit the records, you should define a class (`YourClass`) that has three properties (`AccName`, `AccPhone` and `ParentAcc`) and set the `DataContext` to an `IEnumerable(Of MyClass)`:

```
Select New YourClass With { .AccName = accounts.AccName, .AccPhone = accounts.AccPhone, .ParentAcc = accounts.ParentAcc }.ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You ended a lot of frustration.